# How to use nginx rtmp module to create a simple dynamic overlay on a live stream?

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming

I love the simplicity of the nginx-rtmp-module but I'm unclear how to do something that was pretty simple in Wowza (although don't love Java). In Wowza I could receive the rtmp AMF metadata data in the onTextData event and config a dynamic overlay. It's nothing complex, just some dynamic text that may change very minute or so.

I really have no idea how to do this in nginx-rtmp-module for a live stream. I know how to do this post-processing using ffmpeg, but live I have no clue. This module seems so simple to build out the config file, and the web hooks for start/stop/etc. are really straightforward, but how do I dynamically overlay text on top of frames using this module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think this [link](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) will help you

have you googled it... :)